# Create a link from Indesign to a range of Excel cells via scripting

Tags: excel, hyperlink, scripting, adobe-indesign

In Indesign you can embed links to Excel files which point to a range of cells on a Excel table. I'm searching for a snippet which shows how I can do this using a script. The script would have to fill in the import options of the "File place" dialog which I do not find in the ID scripting documentation.

Comment: I see that this question has been downvoted. Be assured that it makes sense to those who know enough of Indesign and Indesign scripting to be able to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

And the snippet is:

```
var myDocument = app.documents.add(true);
var myPage = myDocument.pages.add();
var myFrame = myPage.textFrames.add();
with (app.excelImportPreferences) {
    sheetName = 'Tabelle1'; // adapt default names to your language
    rangeName = 'a1:b1';
}
var myExcelFile = File( <myExcelDocument> );
var myLink = myPage.place( myExcelFile );
```

The import dialog options are filled in by using the various "Preferences" objects, as listed here http://jongware.mit.edu/idcsjs5.5/pc_Preference.html